# Do English verbs describe actions?

Tags: meaning, grammar, verbs

In this topic in japanese SE:

- [What exactly is a subject](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25667/what-exactly-is-the-subject/25668#25668)

It is stated that in English:

> [A] verb is not an action that can be performed, it is a word that may or may not represent an action.

Is this true? In which sentences a verb is not an action?

Comment: I think it's true, because sometimes it describes state. "I don't know" for example, is a state, not an action.

Comment: but if the definition would be expanded to "it is a word that may represent an action or a state, the definition would be complete, wouldnt be? Or is there something else that can be a verb?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *something else be a verb*. But I remember when I watched a series of video about passive by Geoff Pullum on Youtube, he said not all verbs are performed. You can say *the computer works*, *it's raining*, etc.. and nobody does the actions. IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary definitions of 'verb' include:

> action, state, or occurrence
>
> action or a state of being
>
> action, condition, or experience
>
> action, an occurrence or a state of being

So, everyone agrees on 'action'; no-one agrees on the rest. Note that modal verbs are also verbs, but don't fit into any of these definitions.

Comment: condition and state are more or less the same thing